# Where does the solution using e in an ODE about population growth come from?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Our professor just threw out the truth that the solution to
$$\dot{x} +  = 0 \\  x(0)=x_0$$
is
$$() = _0^{-}$$

I have tried to understand that for an hour now, but fail to do why. Every example on a similar differential equation seems to use some form of dy/dt, which I don't really understand.

Comment: Uh, if you don’t understand what a derivative  $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ is, you can’t expect to understand differential equations. By the way, the community appreciates your efforts in writing the math in mathjax.

Comment: We never used $dx/dt$ in derivatives here, they are always written as $x'(t)$. So it makes using online tutorials really hard

Comment: Oh, so is it only a notational issue?

Comment: Multiply the differential equation by $e^{ at}$ (it is called the integrating factor) and obtain $(e^{at}x(t))'=0$ and then solve!!

Comment: Yeah mostly. We have had derivatives and integrals, but not really where that relationship comes from.

Comment: $\dot{x}$ is a notation that is commonly used to mean $dx/dt$.

Comment: The point is that we are trying to find a function $x$ that has a derivative that is a constant multiple ($-a$) of itself and satisfies $x(0)=x_0$. You can either simply guess the solution $x(t)=x_0e^{-at}$ or do some straightforward integration.

Comment: I like @George Tsoutsinos 's explanation. It do not need $dx/dt$ notation.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, think I got it now!

Answer (score -1):

Use $\frac{dx}{dt}$ notation, it is easier to inverse it.

$\dot{x}=x'(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}=-ax \quad$  The first three terms means the same.

$\frac{dt}{dx}=-\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{x}\quad$ For single variable, you can just inverse it.

$t=-\frac{1}{a}\ln x +c$

$-at+ac=\ln x $

$x=e^{-at}e^{ac}=x_0e^{-at} $

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes more sense!